# NiFi Unable to write flowfile content to content repository

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a simple flow which receive http requests by `handlehttprequest`, process it and push to Kafka. I don't have any error in processors, but I give this warning repeatedly in panel.

> 6 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Unable to write flowfile content to content repository container default due to archive file size constraints; waiting for archive cleanup. Total number of files currently archived = 1198

It seems related to **Content Repository Archiving**, but I don't know how to solve it. Is it possible to disable archiving by `nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled` set to false without affecting to loss data in flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html#deeper-view-deletion-after-checkpointing

The Content Repo then makes the decision whether the Resource Claims should be archived or deleted (based on the value of the `"nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled"` property in the 'nifi.properties' file). **If archiving is disabled, then the file is simply deleted from the disk**. Otherwise, a background thread runs to see when archives should be deleted (based on the conditions above). This background thread keeps a list of the 10,000 oldest content claims and deletes them until below the necessary threshold.